# Expected no type arguments for class "Self"

Tags: python, generics, typing, pylance, pyright

I have a generic class, with a `next` method which returns an instance of itself parameterized to a difference type variable.

I can specify the `next` method's return type using `"` to reference the class itself:

```
DataIn = TypeVar('DataIn')
DataOut = TypeVar('DataOut')

@dataclass
class Msg(Generic[DataIn]):
    source: str
    data: DataIn


    def next(self, data: DataOut) -> "Msg[DataOut]":
        """
        Create a new message with the same source but different data
        """
        return Msg(source=self.source, data=data)
```

I would like to use the [PEP 673 `Self` type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673) to avoid the `"`':

```
    def next(self, data: DataOut) -> Self[DataOut]:
```

But that fails to type check in Pylance / Pyright:

```
    Expected no type arguments for class "Self"
```

[The docs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-generic-classes) say: "*Self can also be used in generic class methods*", but don't show this specific use case.

Is it supported?

Comment: Perhaps the 'Self' needs a lowercase 'S', and the docs are incorrect, however I can't say for sure that it's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported, and not supported intentionally. In case of generic types `Self` refers (in regular methods - not classmethods) to some already parametrized instance.

Quoting [the docs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-generic-classes) (even the same section) that you linked:

> Note that we reject using `Self` with type arguments, such as `Self[int]`. This is because it creates ambiguity about the type of the self parameter and introduces unnecessary complexity:

```py
class Container(Generic[T]):
    def foo(
        self, other: Self[int], other2: Self,
    ) -> Self[str]:  # Rejected
        ...
```

> In such cases, we recommend using an explicit type for self:

```py
class Container(Generic[T]):
    def foo(
        self: Container[T],
        other: Container[int],
        other2: Container[T]
    ) -> Container[str]: ...
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I didn't see that in the docs, thanks 